# How can I get a discord.Guild object that is 'complete' (i.e. has Member.activity and Member.voice per member)? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm Trying to get the list of active users in a particular channel on a discord server (Guild) but if I get the guild with the following function (taken from docs) it gives me an 'incomplete' Guild as stated in the docs as well. Is there a way to get a complete one without using Context from a command?

```
await fetch_guild(guild_id)
```

> This function is a coroutine.
> Retrieves a Guild from an ID.
> Using this, you will not receive Guild.channels, Guild.members, Member.activity and Member.voice per Member.
> Taken from https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Client.fetch_guild (docs)

This is my current code:

```
@tasks.loop(minutes=10)
async def t(self):
    guild = await self.client.fetch_guild(<server id>)

    afk_channel = guild.afk_channel
    for channel in await guild.fetch_channels():
        if isinstance(channel, discord.VoiceChannel):
            if channel.members and channel != afk_channel:
                for member in channel.members:
                    # do stuff
                    print(member.display_name, channel.name)
```

Comment: [`get_guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_guild#discord.Client.get_guild)

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I have already tried that but it returns None for some reason (yes, I used the same Id that returns the correct Guild with fetch_guild())

Comment: Have you waited until the cache is done loading? With `await client.wait_until_ready()`, if the task starts as soon as the bot is launched it will return `None` since the cache is not loaded yet.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński yes haha tried it just a few minutes ago and it worked, Thanks! was about to reply to you but wanted to write a proper answer for the post first in case someone had the same problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had tried `get_guild(id)` as *@ŁukaszKwieciński's*  said in his comment, but it returned `None`, well turns out that was being called too early (the bot wasn't ready yet), so I needed to put `await self.client.wait_until_ready()` before the task (another function with decorator `@t.before_loop`)